# When to install the distribution push notification certificate (SSL certificate)

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

We have implemented push notifications in our app. Now we want to send the app for review, we have installed the development SSL certificate on server.

We want to know that as now we are going to upload the app so we need to replace development SSL certificate with Distribution certificate now or we have to upload distribution certificate after the app gets approved?

Answer (score 0):

add certificates before submission. and must test before submission. if you submit without testing. may be it will cause some problem. you should test the Distribution certificates before sumission.
you can test this on you Adhoc profile of related appID